# NoSuchMethodError while trying to deploy the spring application on Tomcat 9 in Java 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, deployment

My spring web application builds and compiles fine in Java 6. It currently uses spring framework 2.x version jar files.

I am trying to upgrade the application to Java 8. Based upon my research, it seems Java 8 requires spring 4.x or higher. So, I upgraded the spring framework core file to 4.3.30 in the application. The issue is that now I am getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error because 'CollectionFactory' has been removed from the new version of spring core jar file. How do I fix this issue?

Below is the error in the tomcat logs:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.<clinit>(ContextLoader.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.createContextLoader(ContextLoaderListener.java:53)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4769)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5231)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:538)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1690)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1614)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:1026)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:660)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is my application context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">
        
    
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName"><value>java:comp/env/jdbc/tpds</value></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource2" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName"><value>java:comp/env/jdbc/abc</value></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- v Improve performance by loading this code 1 time & sharing it among servlets. v -->

    <!-- VIEW INTERCEPTOR -->
   
    <bean id="viewInterceptor" class="net.taxstream.util.web.ViewInterceptor" />

   
    <bean id="sessionBinding" class="net.abc.core.web.binder.SessionInterceptor">
        <property name="spatialBinder">
            <bean class="net.abc.core.web.binder.StandardRequestLocationDatabinder">
                <property name="paramOrder">
                    <list>
                        <value>clientId</value>
                     
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- ^ Improve performance by loading this code 1 time & sharing it among servlets. ^ -->

<!-- INTERNATIONALIZATION BEANS -->
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="cookieName" value="clientlanguage"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
    
    <bean id="messageSource" name="tsMessageSource" class="net.taxstream.util.i18n.TsMessageSource">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="internationalizer" class="net.taxstream.util.i18n.Internationalizer">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
    
<!-- ACCESS CONTROL BEANS -->    
    <bean id="accessControl" class="net.abc.foundation.acs.rbac.JdbcAccessControlFactory" scope="session">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <ref bean="transactionManager"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- we need to annotate the proper interfaces and classes for this to work
    each method call needs to know what permission to check for -->
    <bean id="rbacAspect" class="net.abc.core.pro.acs.rbac.RbacAspect">
        <property name="order" value="0"/>
    </bean>


<!-- TRANSACTION AND AUDIT BEANS -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource" /></property>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- audit trial stuff -->
    <bean id="gttSessionUpdate" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
       <property name="transactionManager">
           <ref bean="transactionManager"/>
       </property>
       <property name="target">
           <ref local="gttSessionUpdateTarget"/>
       </property>
       <property name="transactionAttributes">
           <props>
               <prop key="*">
                   PROPAGATION_MANDATORY
               </prop>
           </props>
       </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="gttSessionUpdateTarget" class="net.abc.core.audit.GttSessionUpdate">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="audit" class="net.abc.core.audit.AuditAspect">
        <property name="gttSessionUpdate" ref="gttSessionUpdate"/>
        <property name="order" value="200"/>
    </bean>
    
    
<!-- LOGIN BEANS -->    
    <bean id="loginDao" class="net.abc.core.security.ProLoginDao">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
    </bean>
 
    <bean id="proDao" class="net.abc.core.legacy.ProDao" />
    
    <bean id="logoDao" class="net.abc.core.dao.JdbcClientLogoDao">
            <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
            <property name="lobHandler"><ref bean="lobHandler"/></property>
    </bean>  


<!-- IMPORT BEANS -->        
    <bean id="dataImportManager" class="net.abc.core.dao.JdbcDataImportDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
        <property name="cloverUri" value="WEB-INF/foundationModule/clover" />
     </bean>

    <bean id="navigationUtils" class="net.abc.core.util.JdbcNavigationUtils">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
    </bean>
    
<!-- MESSAGE AND LOB BEANS -->
    
    <bean id="extractor" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor" />
    <bean id="nativeJdbcExtractor" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor" />
    

    <!-- WebSphere specific-->
    <!--<bean id="extractor" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor" />
    <bean id="nativeJdbcExtractor" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor" />-->
    
    <bean id="lobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler">
            <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor"><ref local="nativeJdbcExtractor" /></property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="messageDBInteraction" class="net.taxstream.messages.biz.OracleSpringMessageDBInteraction">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
        <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor"><ref local="extractor" /></property>
    </bean>

<!-- INSTRUCTION BEANS -->    
    <bean id="instructionDao"  class="net.abc.instruction.dao.OracleJdbcInstructionDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
        <!--<property name="nativeJdbcExtractor" ref="nativeJdbcExtractor" /> -->
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="instructionManager" class="net.abc.instruction.biz.InstructionManager">
        <property name="instructionDao"><ref local="instructionDao"/></property>
    </bean>
    
<!-- DOMAIN OBJECT MANAGERS -->
    <bean id="clientManager" class="net.abc.core.biz.JdbcClientManager">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="userManager" class="net.abc.admin.biz.AdminJdbcUserManager">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="stateManager" class="net.abc.core.biz.JdbcStateManager">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="unitManager" class="net.abc.core.biz.JdbcUnitManager">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
    </bean>

 <bean id="userClientManager" class="net.abc.admin.biz.AdminJdbcUserClientManager">
         <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
         <property name="userManager"><ref local="userManager"/></property>
         <property name="clientManager"><ref local="clientManager"/></property>
    </bean>

    
    <bean id="assignmentManager" class="net.abc.admin.dao.JdbcAssignmentUtilsImpl">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="navUtils" class="net.abc.core.util.JdbcNavigationUtils">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
    </bean>
       
<!-- SHARED CONTROLLERS -->
<bean id="logoController" class="net.abc.core.web.controller.LogoController">
    <property name="methodNameResolver">
        <bean class="net.abc.core.web.PrettyUrlItemActionMethodNameResolver">
            <property name="items">
                <map>
                    <entry key="logo/name/*" value="ClientLogoByName" />
                    <entry key="logo/id/*" value="ClientLogoByID" />
                    <entry key="logo/ajax/*" value="ClientLogoByAjax" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="clientLogoDao">
        <ref bean="logoDao"/>
    </property>   
</bean>


<!-- ADVICE / AOP CONFIG -->    
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice">
        <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="create*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" />
            <tx:method name="retrieve*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" />
            <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" />
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
</beans>
```

Comment: seems some of transitive dependency is referring older version of spring core & that is reason you are getting this error. Can you please see if removing dependencies solving problem.

Comment: Dependency by another jar file or in the source code? I am not able to find anything..

Answer (score 0):

Several thing s you stated are not exactly true.
But to the point, your exception indicates that versions of spring-web and spring-core are not matching. Or you have some other older spring artifact in your classpath. Check your classpath.

Comment: Hi, can you explain what's not true. Can java 8 work with spring 2.x/3.x?

Comment: if I deploy my project in Java 8 with  springframework 2.5.6 jars (which work in Java 6), I get this error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

Comment: As far as I remember we had Spring 2 apps running on java while ago. Thought I do advice to upgrade Spring as opposed to trying to make your app working with old Spring. If you still need help , ping me